# No module named: I have created 1 module and trying to to use into another program but getting above error. However all predefined python modules fine

Tags: python-3.x

In Jupiter notebook, I have created 1 module and trying to to use into another program but getting above error. However all predefined python modules are working fine. Please help on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How can we reproduce this problem? See [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.